# Tool to catch http request, modify it and send again

Tags: networking, http

I need a simple tool under Windows which can catch some http request, make it possible to modify request headers (manually) and send it again

Comment: ...For what purpose? (there are plenty of legit reasons to want to do this. There are also plenty of malicious reasons...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fiddler http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/version.asp

Answer (score -1):

tcpdump, wget, unix utils for windows (hosted on sf.net)